# Logo not appearing on Mobile Site

Tags: html, css, mobile

When I go to our site on a mobile device or using Chrome's mobile inspector I don't see our logo.

I have tried changing the `display:` settings for the mobile logo, the height of the area, etc. and have had no effect on it. Can anyone see what the problem may be?

Code:

```
<div class="logo_wrapper" style="width: 1921px;">
    <div class="q_logo">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.ladidabeauty.com/" style="height: 80px;">
                <img itemprop="image" class="normal" src="http://www.ladidabeauty.com/wp-content/uploads/la-di-da-beauty-logo-gray-text-white-background.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;">
                <img itemprop="image" class="light" src="http://www.ladidabeauty.com/wp-content/uploads/la-di-da-beauty-logo-gray-text-white-background.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;">
                <img itemprop="image" class="dark" src="http://www.ladidabeauty.com/wp-content/uploads/la-di-da-beauty-logo-gray-text-white-background.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;">
                <img itemprop="image" class="sticky" src="http://www.ladidabeauty.com/wp-content/uploads/la-di-da-beauty-logo-gray-text-white-background.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;">
                <img itemprop="image" class="mobile" src="http://www.ladidabeauty.com/wp-content/uploads/la-di-da-beauty-logo-gray-text-white-background.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;">
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In addition to display:block; it looks like `.q_logo a` also needs visibility:visible;

Comment: Please don't link to live sites. Your code needs to go in the question, including all HTML and CSS required to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this class `.q_logo a` is making your mobile logo hidden

```
.q_logo a {
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Just add this  `visibility: visible;` to this class `header .q_logo img.mobile`

like this :

```
header .q_logo img.mobile {
display: block!important;
opacity: 1!important;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 9999999999;
visibility: visible;//set the mobile logo visibility to visible
}
```